# How to create a "sort by" dropdown input with django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Trying build a webapp using django but having a challenge finding how to create a dropdown input for users to sort items on the page.

Have the filter form:

```
<form>
    {{filter.form|crispy}}
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

is there something similar like?

```
<form>
    {{sort.form}}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="">
    <select name="sort_name">
       <option value="-price">low to high</option>
</form>
```

in views:

```
def funName(request):
   ordering = request.GET['sort_name']
```